# Labels of graph plot shift to right when using format()

Tags: plot, igraph

Please consider the following

```
g <- graph.ring(10)
V(g)$label[1:5] <- 10
V(g)$label[6:10] <- 100000000
plot(g, layout=layout.circle, vertex.label=format(V(g)$label, big.mark=",", scientific=FALSE))
```

which output

[image]

I wonder why the labels of the first 5 vertices shift to right and how to bring them back to the centre of the node.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does have more to do with `format` than with `igraph`:

```
format(V(g)$label, big.mark=",", scientific=FALSE)
# [1] "         10" "         10" "         10" "         10" "         10"
# [6] "100,000,000" "100,000,000" "100,000,000" "100,000,000" "100,000,000"
```

Just remove the spaces and the labels will be centered:

```
sub("[ ]+", "", format(V(g)$label, big.mark=",", scientific=FALSE))
# [1] "10"          "10"          "10"          "10"          "10"         
# [6] "100,000,000" "100,000,000" "100,000,000" "100,000,000" "100,000,000"
```